# breaking into AI after a math PhD

Tags: artificial-intelligence

**TLDR.** Math PhD, currently computational math postdoc, wants to work on AI. Which is a better way: another postdoc (this time CS), start with software engineering / quant, or going back to school?

**Long version.** I graduated my math PhD a couple of years ago and have gradually moved from pure math to applied and computational math. I think that I have good computer skills by now, including experience with ML libraries. However, my actual research is related to technologies that I don't believe to be impactful or even realizable, even though I greatly admire the people in my field.

I am one of those people who believe that AGI is achievable and maybe not far off, and I see no limit to the impact that AI will have on society in the future. With that in mind I feel compelled to try to be involved, even knowing that my contribution will be a drop in the ocean. I do have more specific research ideas in mind, and also a specific set of applications. I am interested in empirical research (not statistical learning theory, for example).

It's difficult to make time to work on projects outside my (old) field in my current position. I am trying to apply to postdoc positions in CS and AI, but it seems unrealistic to compete with CS grads with many ICML papers. Good AI labs in industry are obviously also able to pick from people who have specific AI experience. So I am wondering, is my only choice is to go back to school? Or is it possible to go into software engineering or quant finance and make the move from there to AI research in industry labs?

Comment: It's not quite clear to me whether you want to do academic research on AI, or work in industry. (In industry, the line between research and implementation can be blurry, especially in AI.)

Comment: "I am one of those people who believe that AGI is achievable and maybe not far off, and I see no limit to the impact that AI will have on society in the future." I recommend that you read some articles by people who are more doubtful about AI and the claims about it

Answer (score 3):

This question depends on individual circumstances, like the country in which you reside and want to pursue your career. In general, people with a different background can bring valuable experience to a project. It will depend exactly on your background and on the perceived needs of groups.

Getting another Ph.D. is a heavy investment and the very best CS schools (top 30) will be reluctant to invest in someone like you (at least in my experience). Industry often falls into tailoring their requirements to their current needs, but is in principle open to germinate with employees with different backgrounds.

So, I would advise you to think hard about another Ph.D. Otherwise, just look for opportunities and see your difference as a potential asset.